# Android ListPopupWindow Detecting Click outside of list

Tags: android

I'm using ListPopupWindow which I find very suitable for the purpose with one exception. I want to be able to detect when the user does other than select an item from the list or presses the back button. Currently what is happening is that when an item is clicked outside of the ListPopupWindow list I cannot determine what was clicked and the ListPopupWindow is dismissed. Ideally what I would prefer is for the user to only be able to select an item from the list or press the back button, however I cannot achieve that. I've searched for an answer and experimented for hours but I cannot achieve what is required. As far as I can determine, setting modal to either true or false appears to make no difference. I can obviously detect what is selected from the list, however whether the user presses the back button or clicks outside of the list appear to both dismiss the ListPopupWindow and I cannot determine the action that caused it other than an item was not selected. How can I either detect or prevent other than the user selecting an item from the list or pressing the back button?

Comment: Won't restricting "outside touch dismisses popupwindow" feature resolve your issue?

Comment: I looked at many solutions for PopupWindow and came to the conclusion that they don't apply to ListPopupWindow. As far as I can determine, the two are quite a lot different. There are particular features of ListPopupWindow that I like, and this is the only problem I have with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can determine, this can be solved using

```
android.support.v7.widget.ListPopupWindow;
```

and

```
setForceIgnoreOutsideTouch(true)
```